# оптимизация кода python (циклы)

Tags: python

Я только начал изучать программирование и нейронные сети. вот пишу первую программу. И, может быть, кто подскажет как оптимизировать код, возможно циклы короче сделать.

```
import requests
import json
import time

from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
from datetime import datetime


# Ввод ключа доступа
#key = input('Введите ключ доступа   -   ')   # 'IQLCQLXYBPW3LH7T'
ts = TimeSeries(key='IQLCQLXYBPW3LH7T')

symbolCode = []

with open('CompaniesList.txt') as f:
    listTitleCompany = f.read()
    symbolCode = listTitleCompany.split(" ")

print(symbolCode)
  

# Create Dictinary

countCompany = len(symbolCode)
stockQuotes = {}
lengthDateBase = []

sleepFor = 0
for i in range (countCompany):
    sleepFor += 1
    if sleepFor % 5 == 0:
        time.sleep(61)
    # Запрос данных API
    data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol=symbolCode[i],interval='60min', outputsize='full')

    # Запись нужных параметров в массив
    times = []
    prices = []
    for key, price in data.items():
#            timeD = datetime.strptime(key, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        timeD = key
        times.append(timeD)
        prices.append(price['1. open'])
    lengthDateBase.append(len(times))
    timesPrices = [times, prices]
    # Создание словаря
    stockQuotes[symbolCode[i]] = timesPrices
#    print(stockQuotes)
print(stockQuotes)
print(symbolCode)
print(max(lengthDateBase))
print(len(symbolCode))


# Корректирование длины списков


for i in range (len(lengthDateBase)):
    if lengthDateBase[i] != max(lengthDateBase):
        stockQuotes.pop(symbolCode[i])
 
symbolCodeNew = []        
for key, price in stockQuotes.items():
    scn = key
    symbolCodeNew.append(scn)    
print(symbolCodeNew)
print(len(symbolCodeNew))

# Перегруппировка данных

pdStockQuotes = []
for key, timePrice in stockQuotes.items():
    times = timePrice[0]
    prices = timePrice[1]
    for i in range (len(times)):
        
        pdStockQuotes.append([key, times[i], prices[i]])
           
    
# Запись в файл JSON


with open('TimeSeries.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(stockQuotes))

with open('TimeSeriesPD.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(pdStockQuotes))
```

Comment: Зачем строчки ``timeD = key`` и ``scn = key``? Почему бы не использовать в следующей строчке просто key?

Comment: Тут всё надо переписывать. Сделайте классы под свои объекты и используйте их. Перебирайте объекты, а не их индексы. Сделайте функции какие-то или методы классов и используйте их, а не пишите сплошную простыню последовательного кода.

Comment: Извините, но ОДНОВРЕМЕННО начинать учить программирование и нейросети -  это мягко говоря очень самоуверенно. Нейросети -  достаточно сложная тема. И что-бы реально научиться ее создавать, надо СВОБОДНО уметь программировать. Как минимум - на задумываться над тем, как написать цикл или условный оператор.  Уж про генераторы, исключения, классы и их использование - я даже не заикаюсь. Кто вас на это надоумил?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Посмотрите в сторону map и reduce, как альтернативе for в некоторых случаях. Они работают намного быстрее.